# Quote marks are backwards

Tags: quotation

I am trying to put quote marks around a word, and have been doing it ' 'word", however I am still getting two backwards quote marks. My preamble is

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,prl,nobalancelastpage,aps,10pt]{article}
%\documentclass[rmp,preprint]{revtex4-1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx,bm,times}
\usepackage{appendix}
\def\bibsection{\section*{\refname}} 
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#1#2#3\hrulefill}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=myformat}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-8em}
```

Has anyone got a reason or solution for why this is happening. I will need to put a number of quotes in, so any help for a proper solution is really appreciated.

Comment: You may want to look into the `csquotes` package and its `\enquote` command: `\enquote{in quotes}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX. Please post a *complete code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: the preamble you show isn't  very relevant, the example should be an example of the problem but I think you are doing `''word''` but it should be `\`\`word''`  that is two backtick (ascii grave) on the left and two single quotes on the right, don't use the double quote

Answer (score 3):

In English, you write  quoted ``word'', in German it is ,,Wort'', in Spanish it is 《palabra》. The easiest way out is to use the csquotes package, and write \textquote{quoted}.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish, ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle = true]{csquotes} % Adjust to language

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
  This is text in English.
  Here we quote ``by hand'' and also
  using \textquote{\LaTeX}.

 \selectlanguage{ngerman}
   Dies is auf Deutsch.
   Hier werden zum Beispiel \glqq auf dieser Weise\grqq{}
   Phrasen zitiert.
   Oder \textquote{es wird so} geschrieben.

 \selectlanguage{spanish}
    En castellano,
    tambi\'en se usan signos especiales,
    se cita con <<esto>>
    o \textquote{de esta manera}.
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give a minimum example for each of the languages you mentioned?